# Compilation Error: googlegtest fails with compilation error

Tags: c++, clang++

I'm using googlegtest for testing but when compiling I'm getting below error.

`/gtest-printers.h:389:55: error: no member named 'u8string' in namespace 'std' GTEST_IMPL_FORMAT_C_STRING_AS_STRING_(char8_t, ::std::u8string);`

`/home/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:379:40: note: expanded from macro 'GTEST_IMPL_FORMAT_C_STRING_AS_STRING_' class FormatForComparison<CharType*, OtherStringType> {`

`/home/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:390:61: error: no member named 'u8string' in namespace 'std' GTEST_IMPL_FORMAT_C_STRING_AS_STRING_(const char8_t, ::std::u8string);`

`/home/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:379:40: note: expanded from macro 'GTEST_IMPL_FORMAT_C_STRING_AS_STRING_' class FormatForComparison<CharType*, OtherStringType> {`
2 errors generated.`

It's argument for a macro.

Compiler Version : Clang++ 11.1.0

Compiling inside googletest works but when included as header, compilation fails. Couldn't root cause reason for error?

Can you help why is linking happening to **std**?

`make VERBOSE=1` output:

[VERBOSE Output](https://github.com/KotaHemanthIITD/bitcoin_logs/blob/master/error.logs)

Comment: Are you building with C++20 mode enabled? `std::u8string` is new in the C++20 standard, and it might not be enabled by default in Clang 11.

Comment: no luck after setting CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++20

Comment: Try with `make VERBOSE=1` and paste the output message will be helpful to find the root cause.

Comment: I have attached the link of verbose  output

Comment: I have the same error in GCC11.1.0!

Comment: Mine is GCC 7.5.0 , libstdc++.a doesn’t have u8string when I do nm/use/lib/x86_64/gnu/7/libstdc++.a | grep “u8string” . Still not sure about root cause

Comment: @TheShmoo try installing sudo apt install libstdc++-11-dev libstdc++-11-doc

Comment: Thank you for your hint!
It was not gcc that caused this problem but the cross compilation with the integrated clang-tidy.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a gtest [bug](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/3659): wrong feature check macro is used in gtest-printers.h. As a temporary workaround, you can just edit the header, replacing cpp_char8_t for __cpp_lib_char8_t in a few places:

```
#ifdef cpp_char8_t // <---- should be changed to __cpp_lib_char8_t
//...std::u8string usage...
#endif
```