# c++20, clang 13.0.0, u8string support

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, c++20

I'm using clang 13.0.0 in a CMAKE-based project, CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD is defined as 20. The following code causes a compilation error (no type named 'u8string' in namespace 'std'):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
#ifdef __cpp_char8_t
    std::u8string sss = u8"a";  // <---- this branch is picked up
#else
    std::string sss = "b"
#endif    
return 0;
}
```

Below is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)

project(clang_test)

add_executable(clang_test main.cpp)
```

Am I missing something or is it a clang bug? I mean, if std::u8string is not yet there, the macro shouldn't be defined, right? By the way, if you know the way to undefine it somehow with the CMake, please, share your experience. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67314177/compilation-error-googlegtest-fails-with-compilation-error) the topic starter faces the same problem, I think, but there is no solution proposed yet.

Update: the platform is RHEL 8.4

Update 2: moved the 'project' call below the compiler settings in the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: `I mean, if std::u8string is not yet there, the macro shouldn't be defined, right?` nope. It has partial support for C++20 - enough to allow compiler flag. If one were to wait for full support the macro would be false for a very very long time. They still haven't fully implemented C++17.

Comment: Which platform/toolchain is this happening on? I can't readily reproduce this. My guess is that clang is picking up an older stdlib from elsewhere on the system.

Comment: @ALX23z AFAIK, all modern compilers/stdlibs offer full `char8_t` / `std::u8string` support as of today: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8o1j13T1Y

Comment: The platform is RHEL8.4. @Frank, don't you know how to check if clang (or CMAKE) picks up an older stdlib from somewhere? Or, at least, how to manually point it to the correct one?

Comment: As far as figuring out which stdlib is being used. A simple but janky way to easily do that is to intentionally cause an error in stdlib templated code and look at the paths in the error log. For example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sG4oT8qz7

Comment: Depending on how clang-13 was installed, `target_compile_options(clang_test PRIVATE -stdlib=libc++)` might do the trick.

Comment: BTW, setting a compiler **after** the `project` call is wrong. See that my answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944545/3440745.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Frank's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4442671/frank) suggestion was correct - the problem is in that Clang was using an older version of libstdc++ and not libc++;

```
target_compile_options(clang_test PRIVATE -stdlib=libc++)
```

fixes the issue for me. Though I don't entirely understand why it doesn't work with libstdc++, if you have any idea, please, share it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935157/c-20-feature-test-macro-works-incorrectly-cmake-clang-libstdc) - I assume that this is a separate question.

Also, [Tsyvarev's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) point is indeed a very important one, and the compiler should be set before the project call. I've corrected the example in my question.

Update: Finally I understand the reason why it fails: **__cpp_char8_t** is not sufficient for std::u8string, **__cpp_lib_char8_t** should be used instead.

Thanks everyone for your help!